# enviar valor Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tengo este  html

```
  <div class="m-menu__submenu ">
<span class="m-menu__arrow"></span>
<ul class="m-menu__subnav">
<li id="idTema" value="1" class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item--submenu" aria-haspopup="true">
<a href="javascript:;" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
<span id="Eval_academica" class="m-menu__link-text">Area Academica</span>
<i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
</li>
<div id="grupo">
<li >
</li>
</div>
</ul>
</div>
```

y este js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $("#idTema").click(function () {
                var datos = {
                    idTema: $("#idTema").val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "genera_grupo.php",
                  type: "post",
                  dataType: "html",
                  data: datos,

                  success: function (result) {
                    $("#grupo").html(result);
                  }
              });
            }); 

        </script>
```

pero no se envia nada a el otro archivo no se si estoy enviando bien el valor de li o que error es el que tengo

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis para [enviar por POST en jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) es:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
});
```

En apariencia no estás haciendo nada mal, puedes hacer unos trazados en consola para ver si obtienes un valor para enviar y una respuesta:

```
$("#idTema").click(function () {
    console.log("clicked #idTema ..."); // traza

    var valor_li = $("#idTema").val();
    console.log(valor_li); // traza

    var datos = {
        idTema: valor_li
    };

    $.ajax({
        url     : "genera_grupo.php",
        type    : "post",
        dataType: "html",
        data    : datos,

        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result); // traza
            $("#grupo").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ya funciono gracias, sabes como podria usar ese mismo JQuery pero al momento de usar la funcion click  se borren las variables anteriores , no se si me explico?

Comment: @JV93 puedes hacer cosas dentro del cuerpo de la función del success, como resetear un formulario: `$("#id_del_form")[0].reset();` eliminar los valores de las var JS: `valor_li = ''; datos = {};` no se si te refieres a eso, deberías plantear una nueva pregunta. Saludos.